# If statement inside a function - relationship to the global scope

Tags: javascript, dom, scope

I have been doing one simple DOM game for ages now. And I can't figure out why the scope is the way it is. Explanation is in the code below. I do not understand why one var must be declared inside of a function in an `if` statement for it to work, instead of the global scope. I was dealing with this for literally several hours now and I know it must be simple but now its driving me crazy.

```
//this code does not work - if the var currentScore is declared in the global scope

var
    activePlayer = 1;
    btnRoll = document.querySelector(".btn-roll");
    diceImage = document.querySelector(".dice");
    diceImage.style.display="none";

//var currentScore selects a div - either the one from player 1 or 2

    currentScore = document.querySelector("#current-" + activePlayer);


    btnRoll.addEventListener ("click", function(){
        //after clicking roll dice - generate random num
        var diceNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        diceImage.style.display="block";
        //view a correct image that is the generated number
        diceImage.src="dice-" + diceNum + ".png";
        //if the rolled number greater than one - add to the roundScore
        if (diceNum !== 1) {
            roundScore += diceNum;
//this below should change the text of 0 of a div for player 1 to text of the round score -which it does
            currentScore.textContent = roundScore;


        }
        //else its other players round
        else {
            roundScore = 0;
           if(activePlayer === 1) {
               activePlayer = 2;
  //when I console.log the active player it changes to 2

           }
           else {
               activePlayer = 1;


           }
        }

    });
//problem comes when its suppose to start again - it does recognize that its player 2 but the currentScore variable is stil #current-1 instead of #current-2.
```

For it to work the `currentScore` var must be declared the same way but not in a global scope but in the first `if` statement. Why?

Comment: Do you expect `currentScore = document.querySelector("#current-" + activePlayer);` to keep updating when you change activePlayer? That is not going to happen as you can see. It does not get evaluated every time you use it. Unless you are somehow wrapped in a function that you do not show.

Comment: Your `var` declaration syntax is incorrect. You have semicolons between each variable, which means that only the first one is explicitly declared. The rest of them are *implicit globals*.